# Getting a current or previous value and querying to see if that same field has changed or not

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python and sqlite3 and I am trying to see if a value has changed or not from the last query done comparing to a new query but I am unsure how to do this because I am getting this data from a function from within another function. Here is some code

```
def sim_data_entry():
    data = str(get_sim_number())
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO NumData VALUES(?)''',(data))

def create_table():
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DataTable(data VARCHAR)''')
```

Unsure if that is enough info for you to see what I am trying to do. But I would like to make another variable inside the `get_sim_num()` function and somehow use it to see if the `data` field in the table has changed at all from the last query done.

Here is the sim reader function

```
def get_sim_number():
    try:
       ser=serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
       ser.write(b"AT+ICCID\r\n")
       response = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
       response = response.strip().replace("+ICCID: ", "")
       ser.close()
       print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response = None
    return respone
```

Function calls

```
create_sim_table()
sim_data_entry()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You don't have any queries that fetch the value of something. You're only inserting.

Comment: Okay so in this case I would be using ```previous_val = get_data_entry()``` or?

Comment: `get_data_entry()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Typo: `return respone` should be `return response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I had to do..I had to create a SELECT statement which was assigned to a variable and then I executed that variable. I then assigned a record variable to a cursor.fetchone().Then checking whether the current_sim number was equal to or not the the record[0] fetched from the table. If it was not equal to, I updated that field with the current_sim.

```
def sim_data_entry():
    current_sim = str(get_sim_numer())
    sim_id = 1

    db_sim = ("SELECT sim FROM SimData WHERE sim_id = 1")
    c.execute(db_sim)
    record = c.fetchone()
    
    if current_sim != record[0]:
       print("Not the same sim")
       c.execute('''UPDATE SimData SET sim = ? WHERE sim_id = 1''',(current_sim,))
    else:
       print("Same sim")
    
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the previous value in a global variable.

```
global_data = None

def sim_data_entry():
    global global_data

    data = str(sim_get_number())
    if global_data is not None and data != global_data:
        print("data has changed")
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO NumData VALUES(?)''',(data))
    global_data = data
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245835/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-getting-a-current-or-previous-value-and-querying).

Comment: What was happening was every time i ran the script, that global variable was clearing it. What I need to do is SELECT the last record from the table and compare it to the new value

Comment: It wasn't obvious in the question what you really wanted to compare with.